# how to refresh wpf data trigger ?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, wpf-controls

i have the grid with storyboard as below.

```
<Grid x:Name="grd_Order"   Grid.Column="2" Height="16" Margin="0,-2,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="stry_OrderMsgShowHide"  RepeatBehavior="3x">
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Visibility)" >
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
  </Grid.Resources>
<Grid.Style>
 <Style >
   <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=BlinkOrderAlert,Mode=TwoWay}">
       <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="stry_BlinkOrdAlert" Storyboard="{StaticResource stry_OrderMsgShowHide}"/>
       </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
     </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and in my ViewModel.cs,

```
        private bool blinkOrderAlert;
        public bool BlinkOrderAlert
        {
            get
            {
                return blinkOrderAlert;
            }
            set
            {
                if (blinkOrderAlert == value)
                    return;
                this.blinkOrderAlert = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BlinkOrderAlert"));
            }
        }

        public void BlinkOrdAlert()
        {
                this.BlinkOrderAlert=false;
                this.BlinkOrderAlert = true;

        }
public ViewModel()
{
  this.BlinkOrderAlert=true;
}
```

and it only works first time when constructor is initialized. Whenever i call the BlinkOrdAlert function, it's not working anymore. How can i modify the datatrigger to run storyboard everytime i call the function? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding the following data trigger to you style.
The Following data trigger will remove the story board when the BlinkOrderAlert value set to false and when the value was true it will add story board.

hope this will help.

```
<DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=BlinkOrderAlert,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="stry_BlinkOrdAlert"></RemoveStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>                    
                </DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not really use a `DataTrigger` for this at all, you try use a property like an event which is quite a hack. Unfortunately the native triggers are, let's say not optimal, so you cannot use an `EventTrigger` as it only supports `RoutedEvents`.

But you might be able to use ViewModel-events using the `EventTrigger` from Blend's Interactivity ([Blend 3 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en)) instead, so that might be worth a try.